# Unable to close a stage in javafx through an Action event function

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8, stage

I'm a beginner with JavaFx and I'm experiencing a problem with simply closing a stage. Basically I'm trying to do create a class that's a confirmation box controller. There's a 'yes' button and and a 'no' button, but either way the stage should close and continue with the application:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
// more imports...

public class ConfirmBoxController implements IView {

public javafx.scene.control.Button BTN_save;
public javafx.scene.control.Label label_Message;

private Stage stage;
private boolean answer;
private String title;
private String message;

public ConfirmBoxController(){
    this("Confirmation","Are you sure?");
}

public ConfirmBoxController(String title, String message){

    this.title = title;
    this.message = message;
    stage = new Stage();
}

public boolean confirm(){
    try{
        stage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ConfirmBox.fxml").openStream());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 140);
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.showAndWait();

        return answer;
    }
    catch(Exception E){
        E.printStackTrace();
        return true;
    }
}

public void yes(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    answer = true;
    stage.close();
}

public void no(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    answer = false;
    stage.close();
}
```

Note: IView is an empty interface. 
Basically the stage comes up, I can click the buttons and I know that this is being registered since the functions "yes" and "no" print when I click the buttons. But nothing happens.

I'm sure I'm overseeing something basic, but I haven't found how to do this properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your button a name in the controller class: 
   @FXML
    public Button closeButton;

and add like this method:

```
@FXML
public void handleCloseButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) closeButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
}
```

In your FXML you need a reference to the button name and the method to call onAction:

```
<Button fx:id="closeButton" cancelButton="true" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="767.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCloseButtonAction" prefWidth="100.0" text="Close" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. I don't really understand why, though.

Also, do you know why the functions "yes" and "no" don't change the value of "answer"? i.e confirm always returns the default value of "answer".